# Storing flattened JSON (key-value pairs) with variable value types

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have JSON documents with no defined schema. Each document may have different schema and values.

```
{
    "location":
    {
        "latitude": 58.23,
        "longitude": 25.11
    },
    "building": "A1",
    "active": true,
    "parameters": [ 1, { "scanInterval": 1000 } ]
}
```

These JSON documents are flattened - formatted into Key-Value pairs.

```
{
    "location.latitude": 58.23,
    "location.longitude": 25.11,
    "building": "A1",
    "active": true,
    "parameter[0]": 1,
    "parameter[1].scanInterval": 1000
}
```

**Key** is always **String**.

**Value** can be **String**, **Number**, **Boolean**.

These key-value pairs will be stored in SQL table. The requirement is to be able to filter key-values based on their JSON native values.

```
SELECT .... FROM ... WHERE [Key] = @key AND [Value] > @value; -- [Value] is integer/float
SELECT .... FROM ... WHERE [Key] = @key AND [Value] != @value; -- [Value] is bit/boolean
SELECT .... FROM ... WHERE [Key] = @key AND [Value] = @value; -- [Value] is string
```

Which makes me **question** - **how do I design my table**?

**OPTION A)** **Casting**.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OptionA](
    ....
    [Key] [nvarchar](max),
    [ValueType] [nvarchar](max)
    [Value] [nvarchar](max)
)
```

Always store [Value] as String, when querying data, select rows with matching [ValueType] and cast value:

```
... WHERE [ValueType] = 'Number' AND [Key] = @key AND CAST([Value] AS FLOAT) > @value
```

**OPTION B)** **Column for each value type**.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OptionB](
    ....
    [Key] [nvarchar](50),
    [StringValue] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [NumericValue] [float] NULL,
    [BooleanValue] [bit] NULL
)
```

There are 3 columns. Each column for 1 value type. Out of all 3 columns only 1 can contain value and the rest are NULL.

When querying data, select the column with the appropriate value type:

```
SELECT .... FROM ... WHERE [Key] = @key AND [NumericValue] > @value
```

Which option yields the best results or is/seems overall better? Perhaps there are some other better alternatives?

I'm leaning more towards the A) approach, however all the casting may be adding extra complexity and may have potential performance hits.

Comment: Depends on your use case and basically opinion based. If you are querying these a lot then option B seems better. If you are just retrieving whole objects, perhaps use option A. If you have deeply nested objects the it's probably easier to just leave them as proper JSON objects in the first place (and that is probably what I would do)

Answer (score 0):

A little ugly, and `not fully tested`, but perhaps this will give you a nudge in the right direction.

I should note that `SEQ`uence is optional

**Example**

```
Declare @JSON varchar(max) = '
{
    "location":
    {
        "latitude": 58.23,
        "longitude": 25.11
    },
    "building": "A1",
    "active": true,
    "parameters": [ 1, { "scanInterval": 1000 } ]
}
';

with cte0 as (
   Select *
         ,spath = convert(varchar(max),[key])
         ,seq   = convert(varchar(250),10000+row_number() over(order by 1/0))
    From OpenJSON(@json,'$') 
   Union All
   Select R.*
         ,spath = convert(varchar(max),concat(P.spath,case when try_convert(int,r.[key]) is not null and P.[type]>3 then quotename(r.[key]) else '.'+r.[key] end))
         ,seq   = convert(varchar(250),concat(P.seq,'\',10000+row_number() over(order by 1/0)))
    From  cte0 P 
    Cross Apply OpenJSON(P.[Value],'$') R 
    Where P.[Type]>3
)
Select [key] = spath
      ,value
      ,[Type]  = choose([Type],'string','numeric','bool','array','object')
 from cte0 
 Where [type]<=3
 Order By seq
```

**Results**

```
key                         value   Type
location.latitude           58.23   numeric
location.longitude          25.11   numeric
building                    A1      string
active                      true    bool
parameters[0]               1       numeric
parameters[1].scanInterval  1000    numeric
```